# What is the difference between skewed logistic regression and rare event logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, skewness, rare-events

I was doing a traffic safety analysis.

My understanding is that if I have a sample that the response distribution differs a lot. for example, I have 200 events, but only 20 of them are crashes. I need use the skewed logistic regression right?

However, if i get all qualified crash, that is 100 crash, and then I randomly select 100 baseline events as the control group, I should use rare event logistic regression, because the crash frequency in real world is very low..I need to correct it. right?